# weird characters in utf-8 encoded file

Tags: python, encoding

I used tweepy to download tweets in Spanish and then write them into a CSV file. I used the code below to do this:

```
while True:
try:
    for tweet in tweets:
        print tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.id_str, tweet.author.name.encode('utf8'), tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf8'),
            tweet.user.location.encode('utf-8'), tweet.coordinates, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count])
except tweepy.TweepError:
```

Now, the row containing the tweet text contains weird characters, for example: México, D.F. appears as MÃ­Â©xico, D.F. I tried converting exporting the file to utf-8 in Numbers but this changes the same string to:Mí©xico, D.F.

For other tweets I also get something like this: RT @taniarin: _ôÖ‰_ôÖ‰_ôÖ‰_ôÖ‰ #UberSeQueda.

I am using pandas to read the file with this:

```
pd.read_csv("uber_dataFULL_utf8.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I don't know exactly what the problem is or might be. I used chardet and it detects the text as to be encoded in utf-8.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems to me you're over encoding your text. The CsvWriter/file output should be caring about encodings, not you when calling `writerow`. What Python version is this?

Comment: python 2.7.9, thanks! I can't download again the same tweets, because of Twitter restrictions on past tweets that can be searched only 7 days in the past). So, I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: @user3824382 make a test. Download tweets you know will feature extended characters and test it.

Comment: What is your local encoding ? Is it latin1 or something else ?

Comment: I used sys.getdefaultencoding() in Wakari and it gives me ascii.